# TeamCity post-build action

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

We are using TeamCity Enterprise v.9.1.1
Is there a way to trigger some action after build is complete?
I have tried adding last build step but it executed *before* artifacts are published.

Update: I am not looking for deployment solution. I need a way to specify generic action on build completion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publish artifacts after certain build step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405101/publish-artifacts-after-certain-build-step)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no generic solution at the moment.

You might want vote for the [Post build task feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-38259).

Possible workarounds include:

- adding dependent build configuration (using Trigger)

[image]

- creating new TeamCity plugin (e.g. custom notifier plugin, such as [teamcity-slack-integration](https://github.com/enlivenhq/teamcity-slack) one)

Comment: Thanks, voted for the feature and meantime implemented a dependent build.